# Neo4j Start-Guide (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

does someone know a good beginner tutorial for getting started with `Neo4j`? I downloaded the *hello-world* and *cineast* from **neo4j** examples, but I just can't make it run. I got AspectJ errors and spring errors and everytime I fix an error, a new one appears. I think, the problem is, that I don't really understand, how I have to structure a `neo4j-spring-data` project correctly. Could you tell me, what would be the best way to get a running example for **neo4j**?

Maybe some could post a working **pom.xml** configuration. I tried the configs from the neo4j examples and got exceptions. When I change the aspectj version from 1.6.? to RELEASE I can make the project but then I get a exception in `glassfish` (I deploy the webapp).

**EDIT**

So! Finally I made it working! Here some tipps for other neo4j-newbies:

1. Use `Java 7`! I'm not sure if it was me or java, but it didn't work with java 8 for me!
2. Since `spring-data 3.0` there is the **strict checking** (see: http://blog.neo4j.org/2014/03/spring-data-neo4j-progress-update-sdn-3.html), so you have to define the package of the repositories in the spring config xml! I did it like this:

applicationContext-graph.xml

```
<neo4j:repositories base-package="org.neo4j.app.todos"/>

<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" base-package="org.neo4j.app.todos" />
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" 
  class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
  <constructor-arg index="0" value="http://localhost:7474/db/data/" />
</bean>
```

1. Use the *todo-example* from the *neo4j-examples*, it's in my opinion the simplest of them.

I hope this helps someone.

Best regards

Comment: Your question is about spring data neo4j, not about neo4j proper (and not about intelij). What exactly didn't work when you followed the [tutorial](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/#quick-start) and the [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/)?

Comment: I didn't want to post the error because it was just a configuration problem with many different exceptions. E.g. I used java 8. Now I use java 7, started a new project with the content of the todo-example from neo4j and it works now (less or more). The main reason for this post was to ask for a tutorial. Thank you for the 2 links i will study this! Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways to learn, and you'll probably get lots of opinions (which could mean this question gets closed). But... you're really trying to make lots of things work at once.

f you really want to start learning Neo4j, Neo Technologies has a free [online training course](http://www.neo4j.org/learn/online_course) (which you can get to from their neo4j.org homepage, under *Learn*) that doesn't require anything to be installed, and you'll focus on core features of Neo4j (and Cypher), without worrying about coding frameworks or installing the database engine itself.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is one of the most awesome tutorial I ever saw! Very helpful! Best regards, Maximilian